# Python multiprocessing pool.join() not ending execution

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

This is the code I'm trying to run, with various print() I saw that it stays on the pool.join():

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd

pattern = input('Input the pattern to be searched: ')
pattern = pattern.upper()

def find_pattern(data):
   data['count'] = data['sequence'].str.count(pattern)
   occs = data[data['count'] > 0].sort_values('count', ascending=False)
   return occs['count'].values[:10]

def collect_result(result):
   global results
   results.append(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
   results = []
   for k in [(j*100)+1 for j in range(10)]:
      df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', 
             skiprows=k, nrows=100, header=None)
      df = df.rename(columns={0:'structureId', 1:'sequence'})
      pool.apply_async(find_pattern, args=df, callback=collect_result)
   
   pool.close()    
   pool.join()

   print(results)
```

Code reads a 1000 row file in chunks of 100 rows (sequentially) and then tries to find the input pattern among a column named 'sequence' (paralelly).
I have also tried writing a function that both reads and then finds the pattern, but it doesn't work either (same issue).
All functions have been tested and work in a sequential way.

What could be the issue? What could I try?

Thank you in advance

PS: Here are a few rows of data.csv

structureId,sequence
1,BTYSZGPOVKBXJJEDODJFLBMJWCZPQQACRULZRABYTTEATRTNUDLATOPRTLFGONYVTLHBBLCYNEYIIBCKVCODGCLYNCPSHXHILFHVZKAXFVRVEOBMQASNFPBYPHTJYTYRDNCZZKAZYQHXVPSCQSHXNAUOJTAZEKSRHVVFNDERPTMCXPNYJXAJLHEVFZXNYKETYRCHFJUARRLITSGZRBBTWIOJSMMHVAQUTZZJN
2,SBRXAOYZLABWYJZCVJTGUYAPMBQFJGRLZLCMLMBYRNWPCJMPTCWMSXRSZNWSMYLDSMMNFINTSJZAIHSRARQQBAQLSZXXZZDJVXGYSAHONWPUFRSIDMKZXYEGEMHMOLFNKCDNKZHAFARYWUHCLZULHXKTDPHKHRTMNZXYEJICCXTWROCHCIYSEIEUZZZQBOYWCOYGRGMUSADWZGUYJMBGQKEGGXRJNUEXLWKAGSH
3,LJJFYRXRVYXEYJOAYGQRUWPIGZWPYCHQAGUPADONXCGSWOVXYMAZGBWRGHZSNPSQBTEMOURROTAORTXEPTKPMYUJIAABZCLQNUDDMHKSIRVLWRSGRORJSKGGQLIJIWBUMNGWYTJUZZURKESVIJIZHOPEJWLGSXFKFAKNITKDKSU
4,OIFQEUSWRSTIHYMIFOKOECDBCHYTWHVCZPMLDXXYPZR
5,EDZYAJYHNNDCFNITNNZNUCPSWDYXWGQKTEENLYPPYKXVDTYNBTOTDPRLOJALURGNCWXGHILPGKAMXPACLBLPWULSHWIHQREMBCZLUZNOPXVRHTMIIVOTVXHAVCHQOONJARLVYWAAOHHCLPMQREKWECYIHHWBFTPCOHCNLEIEPUCQPZRCAJRHONQPMKYFGZLAYCMZCDXZLDFJIXQPFUJ

Comment: Could you post a few rows of `data.csv` so that we can test?

Comment: All you're doing, in an extremely convoluted way, is to search for a string in each of the lines in your input CSV file. You'd be better off just opening the file and iterating over the lines contained within it. If the structureId might conflict with the search pattern, just split on comma and search the 2nd token

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, but I have to do this in this way as an assignment (file would have 500K rows).

Comment: In that case you should probably research work managers in general and in particular the multiprocessing.Manager class

Answer (score 0):

I have created a CSV file containing 500,000 lines using pseudo random characters from the range A-Z. The *sequences* in my file vary in length. The total file size is 67.7MB

With a file of that size it's impractical to try to build the modified CSV data (i.e., with the pattern count) in memory. [ I tried it and it's significantly slower on my 32GB RAM machine than the solution presented here ]

So, this approach builds a temporary file in the required format for building your dataframe.

I use two processes for parsing the incoming CSV data and writing to the temporary file. Any more than that doesn't make any measurable difference. In fact, if you think about what these processes are doing, having more than 2 is really pointless.

I have used a fixed pattern. How you handle that is up to you.

This runs in ~3s

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import queue
import pandas as pd
import tempfile
import os
import time

BLOCK = 100
NPROCS = 2
OUTFILE = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'temp.csv')
INFILE = 'bigcsv.csv'

def dosearch(q, v, pattern, lock):
    while True:
        try:
            if (qi := q.get(True, 0.1)):
                oa = []
                for line in qi:
                    i, t = line.split(',')
                    c = t.count(pattern)
                    oa.append(f'{i},{t},{c}\n')
                with lock:
                    with open(OUTFILE, 'a') as out:
                        out.write(''.join(oa))
        except queue.Empty:
            if v.value == 0:
                break


def main(pattern):
    with Manager() as manager:
        q = manager.Queue()
        v = manager.Value('i', 1)
        lock = manager.Lock()
        procs = [None] * NPROCS
        for i in range(NPROCS):
            procs[i] = Process(target=dosearch, args=(q, v, pattern, lock))
            procs[i].start()
        with open(OUTFILE, 'w') as out:
            out.write('structureId,sequence,count\n')
        with open(INFILE) as csv:
            next(csv)
            lines = []
            try:
                while True:
                    for _ in range(BLOCK):
                        lines.append(next(csv)[:-1])
                    q.put(lines)
                    lines = []
            except StopIteration:
                q.put(lines)
        v.value = 0
        for p in procs:
            p.join()
        df = pd.read_csv(OUTFILE)
        os.remove(OUTFILE)
        return df
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    df = main('IAW')
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration = {end-start:.2f}')
    print(df.head())
    print(df.tail())
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't help much, can you tell me why my code is not working? Or what I could try?